# akka-persistence with mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, akka, persistence

Is there an example to persist actor states backed by a MYSQL database?
I am using the https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fsm.html for its finite state machine and want the states to be long lived. I did not find an example to achieve this using a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use akka persistence to do so: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence.html#persistent-fsm

Comment: is there an example with mysql ?

Comment: it's a matter of configuration (mostly). You have to use https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc with mysql